# Why android gallery doesn't has rename option?

Tags: android, filesystems

I am developing an app which captures an image and stores it in gallery with a name returned by the `currentTimeInMillis()` method of `java.lang package`. For better recognition I want to rename those images but i found there is no rename option in the gallery.

Can anybody is there any issue behind not giving this option.

Comment: Are you talking about `android.widget.Gallery`?

Comment: No. The Gallery application in the Home screen of Android.

Comment: But the standard gallery application doesn't show the names of the photos and pictures.

Comment: After selecting the picture, Click menu -> select More -> then select Details. It will show the name, resolution, size, and date of taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gallery application scans the filesystem and shows the pictures as they appear. If you need to change the filename, you can do this with the [`File.renameTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) method.